# Excel - How to create conditional formatting for time where 23:59 < 00:00

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm pretty new to excel and trying to create a spreadsheet for other employees to input a daily time value and have conditional formatting designate the value as 'early' or 'late' based on another cell's value.

This will be based on the inputted time value being lesser or greater than 10 minutes of the scheduled time.

For example: **Scheduled Time = 00:13**; 00:02 = Early; 23:58 = Early; 00:24 = Late

The issue I'm having is how to format the formula so it recognizes 23:59 as being less than 00:00 in these instances. It would also require the inputted/display value to be in a 24-hour format and have the conditional formatting running in the background.

I'm including an image of the intended effect. https://gyazo.com/8674d6c2263df6f2f72db12c51e945e5

I've tried dabbling with instances of =TODAY()+TIME(#,#,#) and it solves the issue of 23:59 < 00:00, but I can't figure out how to make it accommodate the values in D3, F3, H3, and J3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is Date:10-Mar, Actual Time:11:48 PM green? it is late by over 23 hours!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the scheduled time is in B1 define two conditional formatting rules: 1 for Green (define while the current cell is B2):

```
=(B2-$B$1)*24*60<-10
```

and another rule for Red, changing `<-10` to `>10`